# translating sql statement to linq

Tags: sql, linq

I have a working sql statement and want it as linq statement or linq methode chain.

My statement is:

```
 SELECT T1.*
   FROM (SELECT Col1, MAX(InsertDate) as Data
         FROM Zugbewegungsdaten
         GROUP BY Loknummer) as temp JOIN T1
     ON (T1.Col1= temp.Col1
         AND Zugbewegungsdaten.InsertDate= temp.Date)
   WHERE Col3=1
ORDER BY Loknummer
```

Can anybody help me to translate it?

**Edit after comment:**

Ok, my result for the inner select:

```
var maxResult = (from data in context.T1
                group data by data.Col1
                 into groups
               select new
                      {
                         Train = groups.Key,
                         InsertDate= groups.Max( arg => arg.InsertDate)
                       }) ;
```

I tried the join like this:

```
 var joinedResult = from data in context.T1
                    join gdata in maxResult on new
                         {
                           data.Col1,
                           data.InsertDate
                         }
                         equals new
                         {
                           gdata.Col1,
                           gdata.InsertDate
                         }
                    select data;
```

But i get a compiler error by the join that the typeargument are invalid.

In the case that the join works i whould use a where to filter the joinedResult.

```
          var result = from data in joinedResult
                        where data.Col3 == true
                        select data;
```

Comment: It would be better if you would try something first yourself, show it to us and tell us what is wrong with it. Like that you will be able to learn from our answers. If we just give you the solution, you will have to come back the next time you have to translate a SQL query. -1 for no effort shown.

Answer (score 0):

After much more "try and error", I got this version it looks like it works.

```
var joinedResult = ( ( from data in context.T1
                             group data by data.Col1
                             into g
                             select new
                               {
                                 Key= g.Key,
                                 Date = g.Max( p => p.InsertDate)
                               } ) ).Join( context.T1,
                                           temp => new
                                             {
                                               Key = temp.Key,
                                               InsertDate = temp.Date
                                             },
                                           data => new
                                             {
                                              Key = data.Col1,
                                              InsertDate = data.InsertDate
                                             },
                                           ( temp,
                                             data ) => new
                                               {
                                                 temp,
                                                 data
                                               } )
                                    .Where( arg => arg.data.Col3)
                                    .OrderBy( arg => arg.data.Col1)
                                    .Select( arg => arg.data );
```

Could it be that i have to set the same property names (Key, InsertDate) by joins over multi columns?

Comment: "Could it be that i have to set the same property names (Key, InsertDate) by joins over multi columns?" - Yes. How else is the engine supposed to match the columns?